# List of unique elements, given a List of Lists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, set, duplicates

Given an ArrayList `transactions` of sorted Integer ArrayLists, I am writing code to return its unique elements. For example, given

```
transactions = [
  [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
  [2, 3, 6, 10],
  [11, 21]
]
```

my code should return the unique elements, preserving sorted order:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 21]
```

To accomplish this, I am simply adding each element in the each list to a LinkedHashSet, which by its definition keeps the sorting and removes duplicates.

```
Set<Integer> uniqEl = new LinkedHashSet<>();

for (List<Integer> l : transactions) {
    for (Integer n : l) {
        uniqEl.add(n);
    }
}
```

Although my code gets the job done by taking advantage of the Java library, I want a more efficient implementation. Any ideas for a better algorithm to produce a sorted list of unique elements from a list of lists?

Comment: More efficient? So you have actually measured and that is the real bottleneck in your application? (Side-note, why not use a `TreeSet`?)

Comment: `uniqEl.addAll(l)` might be *marginally* more efficient.

Comment: Your result will be `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 6, 10, 11`, which is not the sort order you wanted. Using `TreeMap` like @Tunaki suggested will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to have something more efficient that using a `TreeSet` and adding all lists into this set. A `TreeSet` will sort the elements by their natural ordering ascendingly and it will disregard the duplicates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> transactions = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21), Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6, 10), Arrays.asList(11, 21));

    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (List<Integer> l : transactions) {
        set.addAll(l);
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use Java 8 Streams to one-line that:

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = transactions.stream()
                                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

With this solution, you could run it in parallel but you would have to measure that it improves performance.

Answer (score 2):

If by "more efficient", you mean leaner, then this functional approach might do the trick for you:

```
List<Integer> list =
transactions.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of `l -> l.stream()`, wouldn't the `List::stream` method reference be leaner?

Answer (score 2):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) the following should work:

```
MutableList<MutableList<Integer>> transactions =
    Lists.mutable.with(
        Lists.mutable.with(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21), 
        Lists.mutable.with(2, 3, 6, 10), 
        Lists.mutable.with(11, 21));
SortedSet<Integer> flattenedDistinct =
    transactions.asLazy().flatCollect(l -> l).toSortedSet();

Assert.assertEquals(
    SortedSets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 21), flattenedDistinct);
```

You can also accomplish the same result by using the eager version of flatCollect with a target collection as follows:

```
SortedSet<Integer> flattenedDistinct =
    transactions.flatCollect(l -> l, SortedSets.mutable.empty());
```

To avoid boxing of ints you can use primitive collections available in Eclipse Collections.

```
MutableList<MutableIntList> transactions = Lists.mutable.with(
    IntLists.mutable.with(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21),
    IntLists.mutable.with(2, 3, 6, 10), 
    IntLists.mutable.with(11, 21));
MutableIntList flattenedDistinct =
    transactions.injectInto(IntSets.mutable.empty(), MutableIntSet::withAll).toSortedList();

Assert.assertEquals(
    IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 21), flattenedDistinct);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.